# Runtime error in ionic: Actionsheet missing

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

[image]

[image]

I don't know what is wrong I keep getting this error I keep having Runtime error action sheet module missing

Comment: Hey John, please add more code to this question. the problem maybe located elsewhere your code directory. Thanks.

Comment: I add took some more print screens.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used a package manager to actually get the module ? For example Npm ?

You'll probaly lack the package

Try using these if you haven't so far

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-actionsheet`

`npm install --save @ionic-native/action-sheet`

in your terminal

Answer (score -1):

[I went to my console.log to see what was wrong but i could not find anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAISR.png)

[Now i am in one of the modules it says that i does not exist but i am in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3y8S.png)